# babel-preset-env not changing build size

Tags: babeljs, babel-preset-env

I have an ES6 React app that is being bundled with webpack and using babel. I am configuring babel-preset-env, for node everything is working perfect, but for browser the size of my build is not changing regardless the target percentage. The size is the same when the interval is >1 or when its 90%.

The webpack version is `1.13.1`, my babel version `6.26.0` and babel-preset-env version is `1.6.1`

I have this in my .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "stage-0",
    "react",
    [
      "env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "9.4.0",
          "browsers": [
            ">1%"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "transform-class-properties",
      "transform-runtime",
      "transform-decorators-legacy",
      "react-intl",
      {
        "messagesDir": "./build/messages",
        "enforceDescriptions": false
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `babel-preset-env` it will decide, based on the list of browsers your target, to include only the necessary babel transforms.

It is an alternative to `es2015` and `stage-0`, and including those presets along with `env` is counterproductive, as the transforms included in those presets will be applied whether they're needed or not.

It also depends on how you use `babel-polyfill`. Set it as `import 'babel-polyfill'` at the beginning of your JavaScript entry file, and `babel-preset-env` will replace the import with *individual imports* with only the polyfills needed for the browsers you target.

**I am not sure if it works** that way if you include `babel-polyfill` as part of the Webpack `entry` option, e.g.:

`js
entry: {
  myentry: ['babel-polyfill', 'js/index.js']
}`

Hope this will help you get that bundle size down!

P.S. I'm aware the `babel-preset-env` [documentation is not the clearest](https://github.com/babel/website/issues/1660) when it comes to describing what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `import "@babel/polyfill";` in your `index.js`.

Also, make sure you only import it once. 
If you have something like this

`entry: ["@babel/polyfill", path.join(__dirname, "./src/index.js")],`

in your webpack config, move the polyfill, so it should look like

`entry: path.join(__dirname, "./src/index.js")`